# Sceneform SDK can access all features of ARCore SDK?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I run through all sample provided in both ARCore SDK and Sceneform SDK. But in Sceneform samples, it detect only plane surfaces not Walls. But it works in samples provided in ARCore SDK. 
So there is no wall detection available in Sceneform? And Is there any ARCore feature which is not accessible using Sceneform ?

Answer (score 1):

All the features of ARCore on Android are available when using Sceneform.  The most common use cases are very easy, such as working with objects on a floor plane.

To access the ARCore session you can call [ArSceneView.getSession()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ArSceneView.html#getSession())

You can perform per-frame operations by setting the Scene listener by calling [Scene.setOnUpdateListener()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/Scene.html#setOnUpdateListener(com.google.ar.sceneform.Scene.OnUpdateListener)) then in the listener call ArSceneView.getArFrame().

For example

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.sceneView = (ArSceneView) findViewById(R.id.scene_view);
    sceneView.getScene().setOnUpdateListener((this::onSceneUpdate));
}

private void onSceneUpdate(FrameTime updatedTime) {
    Frame frame = sceneView.getArFrame();
    Collection<Anchor> updatedAnchors = frame.getUpdatedAnchors();
    for (Anchor anchor : updatedAnchors) {
        // Handle updated anchors...
    }
}
```

For ARCore features that require session configuration, you can create the session in your own code and call [ArSceneView.setupSession()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ArSceneView.html#setupSession(com.google.ar.core.Session)) or if you use ArFragment, you can extend ArFragment can implement [getSessionConfiguration()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/ArFragment.html#getSessionConfiguration(com.google.ar.core.Session)) which is called immediately after creating the session.

Just remember if you configure the session directly to set the update mode to LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE.